# How to run Cisco AnyConnect commands in mac OS?

Tags: macos, command-line, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

How can I run Cisco Anyconnect commands in macOS?  I tried running a command, but it only shows me help message. I want to change my `vpn-idle-timeout`, but the command-line doesn't seem to know that any such command exists.

```
knayak-/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin-$./vpn
Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client (version 4.6.00362) .

Copyright (c) 2004 - 2018 Cisco Systems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.


  >> state: Connected
  >> state: Connected
  >> registered with local VPN subsystem.
  >> state: Connected
  >> notice: Connected to myhost.mydomain.com.

VPN> vpn-idle-timeout 100    # I want to run this but it won't work.
vpn-idle-timeout 100

[ VPN Connection commands ]
    connect             disconnect        hosts         stats
    state               block             cancel

[ Misc commands ]
    help                version           exit

  For help with a specific command, try: help <command>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vpn-idle-timeout 100
```

**vpn** binary present in AnyConnect install location can not be used to configure vpn-server (i.e., ASA) commands. You need to ASA-CLI or ASDM to configure tunnel policies like connection timeout, idle timeout etc.,